# How to know the difference on how the TAB key and the space key produce spaces?

Tags: keyboard, text-formatting

What is the difference in using the Tab key and the space key to create spacing between words. Seems they work differently; TAB separates words with "available space" (for lack of a proper term; Im not computer literate) and space key separates words with "invisible but space-filling" blocks? Is there a program, a lesson or an example that can help me visualize this difference?

Answer (score 1):

TAB is often used to align text. The default tab size is often determined by the application. In text mode, the size is usually 8.

Imagine the computer is dumping characters on screen one by one, left to right and top to bottom. When it sees a TAB, it will inject a number of spaces until it reached offset 8, 16, 24, 32, ... whichever come first. Let's say you type `text` and press TAB. Your next input `1` will start at offset 8 (first offset is 0)

```
text    1
```

If you instead of typing `text`, you typed `cat`, the location of `1` will remain the same:

```
cat     1
```

even though `cat` is 1 character shorter than `text`. TAB will always bring the next text to the offset of multiple of 8 (as defined by the text editor or display software).

In addition, if you subsequently add `a` in from of both words, the TAB will not shift the `1` because in both case, the location of `1` have not exceed 8.

```
a text  1
a cat   1
```

This behavior will be very different if space were used. Where the entire portion will shift

```
a text    1
a cat     1
```